# Firebase (Firestore) security rules, limit access to object for specific users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to limit access to Meeting objects stored in Firestore to specific user ids (meeting participants).

Meeting example:

```
{
    name: "Topic 1";
    participantsIds : [
        "0YClg4mgljK8m16znDrW",
        "xFRCam5joc3nDW5jHWT5"
    ];
}
```

To load meetings from Firestore for specific participant I can easily use where query with “array-contains” operator.

How to write Firestore security rule to prevent read for users which are not meeting participants (not in participantsIds array)?

Is there a better approach to store participants on meeting and easily query and write security rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore List type fields show up as [List](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) objects in security rules.  You can use the `in` operator to check if an element exists in a list.  Assuming that you're using Firebase Auth to identify users, this will allow only users listed in the `participantsId` field to read the document:

```
match /your-meetings-collection/{id} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.participantsId
}
```